# Angular (4.x): Cannot use same name attribute for radio buttons

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make some radio buttons to work, but Angular complains about the "name" attribute.

```
  <form>
    <div>
      <h3>Select building</h3>
      <h4>Building search</h4>
      <label for="criteria">Search criteria:</label>

      <input class="radio-input" type="radio" name="building-search-criteria" [(ngModel)]="build_search_criteria" [value]="id" id="id">
      <label class="radio-label" for="id">ID</label>

      <input class="radio-input" type="radio" name="building-search-criteria" [(ngModel)]="build_search_criteria" [value]="name" id="name">
      <label class="radio-label" for="nombre">Name</label>
   </div>
</form>
```

In order to make the radio buttons work, they have to share the same`name`attribute, but seemingly Angular doesn't like that:

```
If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

      Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
      Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

`build_search_criteria`is a string variable. If I understand, since it is bound to the model, its value is defined by the`value`attribute of the chosen radio button.

How can I make the radio buttons work? Thank you.

Comment: Try using `building-search-criteria[]`

Comment: You don't need the value attribute in the template. The two way binding done with ngModel will take care of updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `value` instead of `[value]`.As `[value]` expects a variable.And yeah, it is not giving any ngModel related error to me and it should not.

```
<form>
  <div>
     <h3>Select building</h3>
     <h4>Building search</h4>
     <label >Search criteria:</label>
     <label class="radio-label" for="id">ID</label>
     <input class="radio-input" type="radio" name="building-search-criteria" 
       [(ngModel)]="build_search_criteria"
       value="id"
       id="id">

   <label class="radio-label" for="name">Name</label>

  <input class="radio-input" type="radio" 
 name="building-search-criteria" [(ngModel)]="build_search_criteria" 
  value="name" id="name">
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, in fact, it seems it was not the radio buttons that were causing trouble. It was the text fields following the radio buttons that had the missing`name`attribute, but for some reason (blank lines deletion?) the console was showing me the radio button line numbers. I checked this comparing your code with mine, commenting the radio button code and running the component... the errors were still there! Then I found the real culprits. Thank you for your help.